# How to create an image_tag filter for the rails liquid GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, image, liquid

I'm trying to write a CMS type application and want to allow users to embed images in their liquid page template using a format like {{ page.image_url | my_img_tag }}.

The helper module is just:

```
module LiquidFilters

  include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper 
  include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

  def my_img_tag(image_name)
    image_tag (image_name)
  end

end
```

which I then register during the render:

```
def liquidize(content, arguments)
 Liquid::Template.parse(content).render(arguments, :filters => [LiquidFilters]).html_safe
end
```

However the result that is returned is:

```
Liquid error: undefined local variable or method `config' for #
```

I don't want to create the img tag myself because I'm using paperclip to locate the images from AWS-S3 and I'm concerned that I'd encounter issues.

Any help is very much appreciated - I'm fairly new to ruby & rails.

Answer (score 2):

The code worked when I included an extra two Sprockets modules in my LiquidFilter module. ie the four modules needed were:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper 
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper
```

This use of Liquid enabled people using the simple CMS type application to embed uploaded images in their HTML and these images were pulled in from amazon S3 by the Paperclip GEM running on heroku.

(Thanks to Pascal for formatting my original question).